# netbeans autocompletion when using singleton to retrieve object instead of new operator?

Tags: php, netbeans

when i use the 'new' operator to instantiate a class, netbeans has no problem to autocomplete the members of the object.

```
$instance = new Singleton();
$instance-> // shows test() method
```

but when i use a singleton to retrieve an object it cannot autocomplete the members in the object retrieved.

the getInstance code looks like this:

```
public function test() {
    echo "hello";
}

public static function getInstance() {
if ( ! is_object(self::$_instance)) {
    self::$_instance = new self();
    self::$_instance->initialize();
}
return self::$_instance;
}
```

so i use:

```
$instance = Singleton::getInstance();
$instance-> // no autocompletion!
```

does anyone have the same problem?

how do i work around it?

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could add a comment to indicate of which type `$instance` is, before assigning it :

```
/* @var $instance Singleton */
$instance = Singleton::getInstance();
```

And you'd get autocompletion :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/question-2796730-netbeans.png))</sub>

*(Tested with a recent nightly build of netbeans)*

---

Another solution would be to add a docblock to the declaration of your `getInstance()` method, to indicate that it returns an instance of the `Singleton` class :

```
/**
 * @return Singleton
 */
public static function getInstance() {

}
```

And, then, you'll also get autocompletion :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/question-2796730-netbeans-2.png))</sub>

Comment: i think the second method is better cause then i dont have to add comment every time before calling it. thanks a lot!! u saved my year!! +2 (1 invisible point):)

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;; Yes, the second solution if often better, generally speaking ;; but the first one can be useful in two cases : when you cannot modify the class *(a library, for example)*, and when the method you call can return instances of different classes, depending on the parameter *(i.e. a factory method, for example)*