# Dependency Injection (YADIF), Netbeans and Autocomplete

Tags: netbeans, dependency-injection, autocomplete

I've set up a YADIF (Yet Another Dependency Injection Framework) to handle most application dependencies in a Zend framework app - one problem,it kills auto-complete. 
Has anyone else had this problem? My general solution is to use YADIF for re-usable library classes, but use "new" for application work (i.e. in controllers or items that extend ZF, since I don't want to go to the trouble of stubbing out Zend in my Unit Tests)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer(s) to this inadvertently, so I've added it on behalf of anyone else who encounters this issue:

This solves auto-complete issues for **method scope** - but *doesn't* seem to work for class level variables (i.e. variables preceded by $this):

[netbeans autocompletion when using singleton to retrieve object instead of new operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796730/netbeans-autocompletion-when-using-singleton-to-retrieve-object-instead-of-new-op)

to set up autocomplete for **class instance** variables, use @property:
http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/netbeans/netbeans-autocomplete-on-class-properties-using-phpdoc/